# Go omitempty bool field- not showing false type

Tags: go

I have a struct

```
type Settings struct {
    Status             bool `json:"status,omitempty"`
    AvailableStatus        bool `json:"available_status,omitempty"`
}
```

I am using this struct for saving the data and displaying the data in my GOAPis

for eg if for my save data my json body is like this

```
{"settings":{"status":true,
"available_status":false}}
```

after save I fetch data data using Get-API I am getting like this

```
"settings": {
        "status": true
    }
```

only true data is displaying I need to display both data and need to set omitempty also(omit empty for saving, after that json created and using json I am checking validation)

How can I do this?

for saving the data, all fields are not required.
I might be able to give json like below in my apis body.

```
{"settings":{"status":true,
    "available_status":false}}
```

or

```
{"settings":{"status":true}}
```

I want to do this also. I created json for each model and validation is checking in json .. If I not added omitempty field it will show error available_status is required.

Or any other method for setting available_status  as required filed..

Comment: It's not quite clear why you need `omitempty`... please can you clarify?

Comment: I would also think that you could remove omit empty here.

Comment: `omitempty` is documented to _omit_ `false` values, which is what it's doing.

Comment: @blackgreen 

I updated my question.. I need save and get works in same struct

Comment: perhaps you can use a pointer to bool, so you know when its nil it hasnt been posted at all.

Comment: ,@The Fool , while saving the data json validation fails if I remove the omit empty..

Comment: If you just do json.Unmarshal, you won't get an error with or without fields. https://go.dev/play/p/1QacQ2NvYBA
It seems that there is a problem with the implementation of validation that your purpose cannot be achieved, so it is recommended to write the validation code and ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

"omitempty" is omitting only when value is equal to zerovalue of chosen type. If you want to create custom json from struct you can make map from struct and use json.Marshal or other lib like https://github.com/tidwall/sjson

Comment: I will check this

Answer (score 1):

**Use pointers**

```
type Settings struct {
    Status             *bool `json:"status,omitempty"`
    AvailableStatus    *bool `json:"available_status,omitempty"`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, however your answer could use commentary on why this is a solution.